# automated amCharts-PDF-Export via Crontab?

Tags: node.js, export, amcharts

`amCharts` is a really great engine that comes with a cool PDF-export-functionality.
https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/tutorials/exporting-charts-and-maps-as-an-image-or-pdf/

The problem is, it is client-based. I need to do automated PDF-Exports, with a crontab e.g.

I have no idea how I can do this on NodeJs. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: While it is deprecated, PhantomJS is one tool you can use to render the page containing the chart and then export it as a PDF as a cron job. There's an [old tutorial](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/tutorials/automate-report-generation-using-phantomjs/) on AmCharts' website that illustrates this. Headless Chrome or Selenium are more updated alternatives, but we only have a [v4-based tutorial](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/automating-report-generation-using-selenium-webdriver/) for the latter. Making it work with v3 should be straightforward.

Comment: wow.. thanks dude!! I will have a look on this!